# rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\Routing\Route\CakeRoute.php, line 506]

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am new in CakePHP. I wanted to create menu in cakePHP 2.3.9 but when I run the application it gives following warning "**rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\Cake\Routing\Route\CakeRoute.php, line 506]**"

I am giving the complete code here. I can not understand how to eliminate the warning message above.

At first I have created this file at  /app/Model/menu.php.  Which looks like this

```
<?php
class Menu extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Menu';
    var $useTable = false;

    function main ($selected = 'home') {
        return array(
            'divClass' => 'menu',
            'ulClass' => 'menu',
            'tabs' => array(
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'pages',
                        'action' => '',
                        'params' => '',
                        'aClass' => $selected == 'home' ? 'selected' : '',
                        'liClass' => '',
                        'text' => 'Home'
                    ),

                    array(
                        'controller' => 'pages/service',
                        'action' => '',
                        'params' => '',
                        'aClass' => $selected == 'Service' ? 'selected' : '',
                        'liClass' => '',
                        'text' => 'Service'
                    ),

                    array(
                        'controller' => 'pages/user',
                        'action' => '',
                        'params' => '',
                        'aClass' => $selected == 'users' ? 'selected' : '',
                        'liClass' => '',
                        'text' => 'Users'
                    ),
            )
        ); // end return
    } // end Main

 } // end class Menu
?>
```

Then I have created this file at /app/Controller/MenusController.php. Which looks like this

```
<?php
class MenusController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Menus';
private $menus;

function beforeFilter () {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->menus[] = array(
                        'name' => 'main',
                        'selected' => 'users'
                    );

 //        $this->set('menuList', $this->menus);
}

function index() {
    $this->menus[] = array(
        'name' => 'users',
        'selected' => 'users'
    );

  $this->set('menuList', $this->menus);  
}

function menus($menus) {
    $output = array();

    foreach ($menus as $menu):
        $output[] = $this->Menu->{$menu['name']}($menu['selected']);
    endforeach;

    return $output;
}

}

?>
```

Then, this file I have created at /app/View/Elements/menu.ctp, which looks like this

```
<?php
if (empty($menuList)):
$menuList = array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'main',
                    'selected' => 'home'
                )
            );
endif;

$menus = $this->requestAction(
array(
    'controller' => 'menus',
    'action' => 'menus'
),
array('pass' => array( $menuList))
);

if (! empty($menus)):
foreach ($menus as $menu):
    $tabs = '';
    foreach ($menu['tabs'] as $tab):
        $url = array(
                'controller' => $tab['controller'],
                'action' => $tab['action']
               );
        if (! empty($tab['params'])):
               $url[] = $tab['params'];
        endif;

        $tabs .= $this->html->tag(
            'li',
            $this->html->link(
            $tab['text'],
            $url,
            array('class' => $tab['aClass'])),
            array('class' => $tab['liClass'])
        );
    endforeach;
    echo '<div class="' . $menu['divClass'] . '">
          <div class="container_12">
          <div class="grid_12">' . $this->html->tag('ul', $tabs, array('class' => 
    $menu['ulClass'])) . '</div></div></div>';
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

accept my advance gratitude for help

Comment: We would gladly help if you would post some code along with your error message.

Comment: I have modified my question by giving the code. I can run the application but can not eliminate the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Your framework might have a default helper function which uses php's rawurlencode() function by default too. You might want to check the parameters you should pass for $this->html->link() since php's rawurlencode() function accepts only a string as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation says requestAction now supports 'array based cake style URLs' which 'bypass the usage of Router::url()', try passing a string as the first parameter to request action.

For example where you currently have:

```
array(
  'controller' => 'menus',
  'action' => 'menus'
),
```

Try:

```
'menus/menus',
```